# Reversing string in C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reversing

In the following part of the string swap code

```
 end = &str[len - 1];
```

I am not understanding the addressing part. When I do it without the addressing part it still runs but gives me a warning that "a values of type char cannot be assigned to identity of type char". Here is the full code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstring>
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[] = "This is a test";
    char *start, *end; 
    int len;
    int t; 

    cout << "Original " << str << "\n";
    len = strlen(str);
    start = str;
    end = str[len - 1];  

//this reverses the string
    while (start < end) { 

        t = *start;  
        *start = *end; 
        *end = t; 

        start++; 
        end--; 

    }
    cout << "Reversed" << str << "\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Reversing string in **C++**"* not like this, please. Not like this. I respect C and C programmers, and what is theirs, shall be given to them. You Have a dedicated type for strings, you have algorithms, you have `swap`... c++ is not only `cout`. Sorry, for complaining, but I feel kinda saddened.

Comment: I am working examples through a textbook.

Comment: I would red flag it. Seriously. I would consider it harmful. It teaches you obsolete things. You would never have such a problem in a proper c++ program... or is it a C book? This looks like C code with `cout`. That is how C programmers used to teach c++ 15-20 years ago. At least that is my experience.

Comment: I am using C++ Beginner's guide second edition by Herbert Schildt. Is there a better book you would recommend for beginners like myself?

Comment: I do have one follow up question pls. How come the following does not need to be pointing to an address:                         start = str;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not understanding the addressing part.

Given

```
char str[] = "This is a test";
char *start, *end; 
len = strlen(str);
```

then `end` is pointer to char, and

```
end = &str[len - 1]; // `end` points to the last character (before the `\0`)
```

You must use the `&` (address of) operator because `end` is pointer and so it must be assigned to the address of something (here the address of the last character of the string).

> When I do it without the addressing part it still runs

I don't think it will - you should have got a compile error

```
end = str[len - 1]; // invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’
```

Comment: I do have one follow up question pls. How come the following does not need to be pointing to an address:                         start = str;

Comment: @Jeff - that's because `str` is a string (not a single character)

Answer (score 0):

You should konw the type of `end` is `char*`, but the type of `str[len-1]` is `char`, so you need change type `str[n-1]` to `char*`, so you need `&str[len-1]`.

But if you use `string`, there will be an easy method:

Use the std::reverse method from [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library):

std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());  //str shoud be string type

You will have to include the "algorithm" library, #include.

Comment: Your post doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: @RSahu The OP didn't actually ask a question. A reasonable guess is that the question is "what's a sensible way to reverse a string in C++".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, they kinda of did: *I am not understanding the addressing part*

Comment: I understand that as the difficulty they ran into trying to solve their actual problem -- how to reverse a string. And the right answer, if that's the question, is not to do it such a horrible way. But this highlights why it's extremely important for someone, after pushing the `Ask Question` button, to actually *ask* a *question*.

Comment: I appreciate both answers. I understand why you still need it and now understand that there is a better way to accomplish it. I will be more specific next time but the question is answered. Thank you!!!

Comment: Would you mind editing this into a full-fledged answer with a complete code example? I believe it would serve OP really nice, to see how a proper c++ solution looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
void reverse (char word[])
{
   int left = 0;
   int right = strlen(word) - 1;

   while (left < right)
   {
      char temp = word[left];
      word[left] = word[right];
      word[right] = temp;
      left++;
      right--;
   }
   cout << word;

}
```

I hope this gives you the idea.